# http.sys implementation

Tags: windows, communication, winsock, http.sys

We all know that there's a big sweet piece o' binary named http.sys **kernel-mode driver** in our Windows that does HTTP handling for us. That is basically all we know about it.

But today I thought: hey, all our networking stuff like TCP/IP and whatnot is here, in userland -- ws2_32.dll's providers (in mswsock.dll) and all its friends. Since there are userland components, there is no way http.sys uses them. The question is: how do they do it? Any informative links will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got the wrong mental model of what http.sys does.  It merely solves a problem with too many programs wanting to listen on port 80.  There's a decent article at codeproject.com: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that HTTP.SYS utilizes [Windows Kernel Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to achieve it's objectives.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/02/24/538746.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

`http.sys` is only meant to be used as server component listening for HTTP/HTTPS requests - basically IIS depends on it to achieve good performance. It is not used to make any client requests using Winsock library. You can read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager).

Comment: That is true. But that is not what I've asked. What I'd like to know is how http.sys does its network communication.

Comment: Its network communication is rather limited - it only needs to create listening socket and check what is coming on that socket, and then expose this info to user-space apps. You do not need a lot of brain power to do this

Comment: Agreed. Again, the question is -- **how**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found a good answer to the question here: http://www.codemachine.com/article_tdi.html

It appears that there is much, much more to networking in Windows than Winsock shows us.