# How does IIS know that a web request is for ASP.NET and not for something else?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

When a request comes into IIS, how does IIS know that the request is for ASP.NET and not for something else like, say, PHP.

I am guessing that it doesn't. All IIS does is look up the domain requested for in the HTTP request header and route the request to the application hosted in the IIS that is running on that website name. But then what does aspnet_isapi.dll do in resolving the request? Does the library come into action only once the request is already within ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

You've got it pretty much right.  IIS basically acts as a controller for any web applications that might want to respond to a given request.  When a request comes in, IIS routes it to the appropriate app by checking the request against defined bindings. If it finds a matching binding, it checks to see if the corresponding application has been initialized, and if not will perform that initialization.  Then it passes the request on, and the web application does all of the actual work in processing the request and generating a response.

Importantly, a web application is not necessarily synonymous with an asp.net website or application. IIS can also host mail servers, ftp sites, (I believe) php applications, and more.  In each case, however, a binding must still be defined and there must be an engine that IIS can initialize and query the state of.

Comment: As for how requests get to IIS as opposed to some other software running on the system, that's [a whole other question entirely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895542/http-sys-implementation).